# Can We Use Articles Before Adjective And Adverb

Tags: adjectives, articles

I want to ask if we can use an article before any adjective or adverb.

(https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-types)

Comment: You've been posting variations of this. I think a translation service would help immensely. I will vote to move this to the sister site ELL, which may be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, we can, but an article is related to a following noun in this case. For example:

> This morning I saw **a big red and green** bird in the tree.
>   Two cars passed us. **The blue one** was catching up with **the grey one.**

An article can also be a part of a whole collocation, e. g.: *a little bit, a little, a few, a trifle.*

As for articles before *adverbs,* the example is: ***a very*** beautiful girl.

Comment: ok means we can use them in both adjective and adverb and the two case you have mentioned is about where it defining a noun

Comment: In all bolded examples it defines a noun.

Comment: ok thank you for your valuable guidance

Comment: You're very welcome :)

Comment: _**A**_ beautifully expressed answer.

Comment: @fev: if it's not only an example, then thanks a lot! ;) And for the vote, which I guess was yours.